# How can i manage no of the sections with no of rows in UItableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I am developing a Tab Bar Application in which My need  like

I Have a table view in which I have 9 rows (name of acct Groups) which are in one array. When I select any row it opens another view and I enter `AcctTitle` and save it. When I click On another tab it opens a table view and It should display rows according to acct group.

I mean that when I select xxx group in previous tab and enter 5 acct Title one by one and save it, in other tab it should display xxx group as a header of section and 5 titles as row in that section.

Different groups have different rows (two different tab). How can I do that?

Comment: So if I understand well, your question is how to communicate the view with your table view where you enter the rows one by one and the view in the other tab where to show the title and the rows with what you have entered?

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution but you could solve this with a singleton class that have the information of the arrays you need to show on the tabBar view. Don't save the arrays in the tableView but in the singleton. With that solution all the viewControllers than need the information have the same, so show the same information

Comment: can i have to take different array for Each Group?

Comment: In the singleton class you should save only the arrays that should be shared between view controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this two methods

```
//For Number of section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

//For Number of Cell
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [tableview reloadData]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the section value change they all are in different different group use these method.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
   if(section==0)
   {
    //what ever you want
   }
   if(section==1)
   {
   //what ever you want
    }
   }


  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
  if(section==0)
  {
  //what ever you want
    }
  if(section==1)
  {
  //what ever you want
  }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an array with list of sections u need to display. and in

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{ return [urSectionlistArray count]}
```

and in the method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ return [urSectionlistArray objectAtIndex:section]count];
```

define the no of rows based on the different sections defined.

U can define the title of the headers in the method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return [urSectionlistArray objectAtIndex:section];
```

}

U can try the above approach..